# Freeze the values ​of a slicer when I leave the sheet

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have multiple pivot tables and each of them is linked to one or two slicers. They adjust when I filter by values or conditions but when I want to go to another sheet of my document.

The problem is that in a third sheet I have a table that resumes the information in my pivot table: but in this third sheet the slicer is not applied so instead of having just the data that I've filtered, I have all the information.

I know that you can freeze the values of the slicer but when I click on the three little dots,
it does not ask me to set the current filters by default.

Can someone help me with this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you mean I think, and have come up with a workaround.

The issue as you say is that you setup data slicers to filter the data, then in another sheet you want to use that data to create (in my case) and invoice or similar. When you switch to the invoice sheet, the data flashes in place momentarily before being replaced with the wrong or no data - this seems to be because as you switch between the sheets the data slicers reset (or don't hold) - you can see this if you switch back, you'll see briefly all the data before it rememeber what you set the slicer to and then filters it again - a bug in my opinion.

Workaround - copy the slicer(s) and paste the copies into the sheet where you want to use the data (I had to set the background colour and text colour to white so they didn't show up on the printout)....that seems to do the trick, a bit clunky, hopefully Google will fix!